# Make scroll function with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web with a fixed navbar menu.

I want to make a scrolling function to a specific element, so if click a menu, it should scroll to that element.

Actually, it's working when I use scrollToView(), but because scrollToView() will scroll element to top of 0, so some of the element is behind the navbar.

How to specify the top of the element, so that the element scrolls under the navbar.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this step by step:

1. find the element to scroll into view
2. calculate the element's scroll position from top
3. calculate the height of the navbar
4. scroll to the required position

.

```
const el = document.getElementById("idOfTheElement"); // step 1
const elFromTop = el.offsetTop; // step 2
const navBarHeight = 60; // step 3 (considering it is of fixed height)
window.scrollTo(0, elFromTop - navBarHeight); // step 4
```

Here i've considered the navbar to be of fixed height. If the height of navbar is dynamic, you'll have to calculate the height using `el.offsetHeight`.

`window.scrollTo` will scroll the element without any animation. For smooth scroll use:

```
el.scrollTo({
  top: x,
  left: y,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

but the above function has browser incompatibility. What I usually do is create a custom function and use that:

```
function smoothScroll(x, y, el = window) {
  try {
    el.scrollTo({
      top: x,
      left: y,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  } catch (e) {
    el.scrollTo(x, y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On modern browser you could obtain the same behaviour with CSS only using the `scroll-margin-top` property and a link to an anchor.

When you click on the link the page will scroll until the `#section-1` block, but thanks to the `scroll-margin-top` property you will define some margin above the element only on scroll, so the section will be visible just below the fixed header. Of course this requires to know in advance the height of the fixed element.

```css
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
   --headerheight: 80px;
}

header {
  position:  fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--headerheight);  /* e.g. 80px */
  background: #9bc;
}

section {
  /* e.g. 85px */
  scroll-margin-top: calc(var(--headerheight) + 5px);
  height: 100vh;
  color: #333;
}

header + section { 
  padding-top: calc(var(--headerheight) + 5px); 
}
```

```html
<main>
   
   <header>Fixed Header</header>
   
   <section id="home">
      <a href="#section-1">Scroll to section 1</a>
   </section>
   
   <section id="section-1" >
      section 1 <br/>
      <a href="#home">Scroll up</a>
   </section> 
   
</main>
```